# Order of elements - abstract algebra. Subgroups/generator system

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have some difficulties in solving this type of problem.

Let G = Z/9Z x Z/18Z .

1. Find order of elements : (4,3) and (3,5).
2. Is it true that (4,3) belongs to the subgroup generated by < (3,5) > ? But (3,5) in <(4,3)>?
3. Elements { (4,3) , (3,5) } forms a generator system for G?

I know that order means that number when multiplied with (a,b) should be (0,0) but I don’t know if I’m correct.

I found ord(3,4)= 18 and same for (3,5). 
For 2 and 3. I have no idea how to solve.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the order of $(a, b)$ is the minimum integer $n > 0$ such that
$$ n \cdot (a, b) = (a, b) + \ldots + (a, b) = (na, nb) = (0, 0).$$
The order of $(a, b)$ is the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$ because

1. the order of $(a, b)$ divides the order of $a$ and $b$,
2. it is the smallest positive integer with this property.

The results for the first point are correct.

For the second point, you want to show that there exists an integer $n$ such that $n \cdot (4, 3) = (3, 5)$ in $G$.
This means in particular that $n \cdot 3 = 5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(18)$, which is impossible (why?). Therefore the claim is false. The second question in (2) has a similar solution.

For the third point there different ways to solve it.

One (long) way would be to consider the intersection $H_1 \cap H_2$, where $H_1 = \langle (4, 3) \rangle$ and $H_2 = \langle (3, 5) \rangle$.
Then
$$|H_1 H_2| = \frac{|H_1| \cdot |H_2|}{|H_1 \cap H_2|} $$
hence they are a system of generators if and only if
$|G| = |H_1 H_2|$, which is equivalent to $|H_1 \cap H_2| = 2$.
Clearly $|H_1 H_2| \geq 2$ since $|H_1 H_2| \leq |G|$, we need to show the other bound.

Note that $(0, 9) = 9 \cdot (4, 3) = 9 \cdot (3, 5) \in H_1 \cap H_2$, hence $2$ divides $|H_1 \cap H_2|$.

Since $|H_1 \cap H_2|$ is a proper divisor of $18$ which is divisible by $2$ there are only two options: $2$ or $6$.

The intersection $H_1 \cap H_2$ has order $6$ if and only if it contains an element of order $3$.

The elements of order $3$ in $H_1$ are
$$
6  \cdot (4, 3) = (6, 0) \\
12 \cdot (4, 3) = (3, 0)
$$
while the elements of order $3$ in $H_2$ are
$$
6  \cdot (3, 5) = (0, 12) \\
12 \cdot (3, 5) = (0, 6)
$$
hence $H_1 \cap H_2$ has no element of order $3$, and $|H_1 \cap H_2| = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, determining whether $(4,3)$ is in $\langle (3,5) \rangle$, think about whether there exists $n$ such that $3n \equiv 4 \pmod{9}$ (which is necessary to obtain $4$ in the first component). Similarly, for whether $(3,5)$ is in $\langle (4,3) \rangle$, think about whether there exists $n$ such that $3n \equiv 5 \pmod{18}$ (which is necessary to obtain $5$ in the second component).

For question 3, you want to determine if all members of $G$ can be expressed in the form $m(4,3) + n(3,5) = (4m + 3n, 3m + 5n)$ for integers $m,n$.

One approach is as follows: assume for a fixed $k$ that $3m + 5n \equiv k \pmod{18}$. Since $5^{-1} \equiv 11 \pmod{18}$, this is equivalent to the congruence $n \equiv 11 (k - 3m) \equiv 11k + 3m \pmod{18}$. Now, given $\ell$, can you show that there exists a choice of $m$ such that $4m + 3n \equiv \ell \pmod{9}$? If you can, then letting $n = 11k + 3m \mod 18$ gives values of $m$ and $n$ which satisfy $3m + 5n \equiv k \pmod{18}$ and $4m + 3n \equiv \ell \pmod{9}$.